# Ansible run_once with_items

Tags: post, ansible, runonce

Trying to run this task in Ansible only on the first item in with_items. I am not able to change the cluster_server_names variable as it is used elsewhere. Do I need a separate task to register a new variable containing only the server name I want or is there another way possible?

```
   - name: "Provision public IP in dev"
     uri:
       url: "{{ api_url }}/servers/{{ item }}/publicIPAddresses"
       headers:
         Authorization: "REMOVED"
         Content-Type: "application/json"
         Accept: "application/json"
       method: POST
       body_format: json
       status_code:
         - 200
         - 201
         - 202
       body:
         ports: [{"protocol":"TCP","port":"80"}]
     no_log: false
     register: blueprint
     run_once: true
     with_items:
       - "{{cluster_server_names |json_query(get_server_names)}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I do not have a way to test this, but try the `first` filter:

```
- name: "Provision public IP in dev"
  uri:
    url: "{{ api_url }}/servers/{{ server }}/publicIPAddresses"
    headers:
      Authorization: "REMOVED"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    status_code:
      - 200
      - 201
      - 202
    body:
      ports: [{"protocol":"TCP","port":"80"}]
  no_log: false
  register: blueprint
  run_once: true
  vars:
    server: "{{cluster_server_names | json_query(get_server_names) | first }}"
```

Comment: @Tevor Great!  Hit the Accept Answer for me please! :)